# Divergence free vector fields in general measure space

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, optimal-transport, gradient-flows

I'm reading Ambrosio's *Gradient Flows in Metric Spaces and the Space of Probability Measures* textbook, and I'm stuck on a part of Lemma 8.4.2. Rather than give the whole Lemma, I'll state the specific claim I'm confused by, and I'll simplify it by taking $p = 2$ ($p = 2$ is the only case I'm interested in), $X = \mathbb{R}^n$ (rather than some other separable Hilbert space $X$).

Here $\mu$ is a finite Borel measure on $X$, and $v,w$ are $L^2(\mu)$ vector fields (the integral of $|v|^2$ w.r.t. $\mu$ is finite). The statement is as follows:
\begin{equation*}
\int_X v \cdot w \, d \mu(x) = 0 \, , \text{ for any $w \in L^2(\mu)$ s.t. $\nabla \cdot (w \mu) = 0$}
\end{equation*}

is equivalent to
\begin{equation*}
v \text{ belongs to the $L^2(\mu)$ closure of } \{\nabla \phi \, : \, \phi \in C_c^\infty(X)\} \, . 
\end{equation*}

Some clarifications:

- $\nabla \cdot (w \mu) = 0$ means that, for any test function $\phi \in C_b^1(X)$, $$\int_X \nabla \phi \cdot w \, d \mu = 0 \, . $$
- The second statement means that there is some sequence $\{\phi_n\} \subseteq C_c^\infty(X)$ so that $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_X |\nabla \phi_n - v|^2 \, d \mu = 0 \, . $$

**Why is the stated equivalence true???** (The textbook states it without justification.)

I think the backward implication is clear: if we can write $v = \nabla \phi$ for some $\phi$, then $\nabla \cdot (w\mu) = 0$ means precisely that $\int_X v \cdot w \, d \mu = 0$.

However, the forward implication is unclear to me. If $\mu$ were just the Lebesgue measure/some absolutely continuous measure w.r.t. Lebesgue then I would try integration by parts (looks like some Sobolev thing going on), but I don't believe this is available to us here? I can't find any integration by parts formulas for arbitrary measures in the textbook.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With all definitions given, the statement is more about Hilbert spaces (in this case $L^2(\mu)$), than anything else.

Notice that the first condition is that $v$ is orthogonal to the set of divergence free  vector fields, while the second condition is that $v$ is orthogonal to the orthogonal complement of smooth gradient fields (recall double orthogonal complement gives the closure of a subspace).

By definition, if $u$ is orthogonal to smooth gradient fields then it's divergence free (this can be justified by approximating $C^1_b$ functions by $C^\infty_c$ ones in an appropriate way) and so by hypothesis $u\perp v$, which gives the implication.

Comment: +1 Thanks a lot for the quick and clear answer. That resolves it for me; looking at the whole proof of that lemma, it seems to be, as you said, an argument more about Hilbert spaces than anything else.